# How to build a gradle project without a specific subfolder?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I have a Kotlin project in Gradle with 3 main folders: `myorg.folder1`, `myorg.folder2`, and `myorg.folder3`. Due to project constraints I cannot change this structure. As part of the project, I would like to have two different `jar` distributions: One containing all 3 folders, and one that only contains `folder1` and `folder2`. The project has been set up so that these folders can operate independently of `folder3` without errors. How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far? I guess you just need to configure 2 source sets and 2 jar tasks - according to Gradle docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, (following broot's advice, thanks), I was able to find that I needed to use a `sourceSet` to make this work.

```
sourceSets {
    noFolder3
        kotlin {
            exclude "myorg/folder3/**"
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I can build with all 3 folders using `build`, and without `folder3` using `build noFolder3`.

One extra note is that since I was using Intellij IDEA, all of my code was stored in the directory `src/main/kotlin`, so I also added the following line inside the `kotlin {}` block:

```
srcDirs += "src/main/kotlin"
```